# I have to find the inverse of $h(x)=f(2x)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I have to find the inverse of $h(x)=f(2x)$

We know that $y=f^{-1}(x)\Longleftrightarrow x=f(y)$ and if we use that we get.
$$y=h(x)=f(2x)\Longleftrightarrow x=h(y)=f(2y)$$
$$x=f(2y)$$ 
$$2y=f(x)$$
$$y=\displaystyle\frac{f^{-1}(x)}{2}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Another way to see this is to write $g(x)=2x$, so $h=f\circ g$ and $h^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your final answer is indeed correct but your working is confusing - maybe they're just typos.

Anyway, here's my working:

Let $y = h(x)$. Hence $x = h^{-1}(y)$

Now,
$$h(x) = f(2x)$$
$$h(h^{-1}(y)) = f(2h^{-1}(y))$$
$$y = f(2h^{-1}(y))$$
$$f^{-1}(y) = 2h^{-1}(y)$$
$$h^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{2}f^{-1}(y)$$
$$h^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{2}f^{-1}(x)$$

Comment: There are too many h to handle with, and a bit confusing

Comment: But I think I got it